# How to use json.dumps() to render python object in Flask app?

Tags: python, json, templates, flask

Hi all: I'm using Flask to develop a simple web app. I have a python function that return a collection of objects that I then want to render inside a template (i.e `{{ object1.value }}`) in a html page. I was thinking about creating a dictionary containing the object values that would then be passed on to the page as a jsonify string through a GET request.

The Flask app looks like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():

    python_func(object1,object2,object3...)
    data = json.dumps({object1.key: object1.value, object2.key: object2.value ...})

    if request.is_xhr:
        return jsonify(data=data)
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('main.html',data=data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The html page looks like this:

```
 <div class ="dice">
         <div class ="dice-1">
            <div class="card" id ="card1" >

                <p>{{ data }}</p>

          </div>
        </div>
```

And script with an event button. When button is clicked the object values are updated:

```
<script>

         $(function() {
                $('#roll-button').click(function() {
                    $.get('/', function(data){ 
                     document.getElementById("card1").innerHTML = data.data;

                    })
                });
           });



</script>
```

This seems to work to pass the object values to the template. I can see a string object with all the object keys and values when I update the page.

My problem is that I don't know how to use the string inside the template. I am confused about the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html) on the subject about decoding json.

Hence this question: how can parse the string containing all the object values to render inside the template to ideally look like this: `{{ object1.value }}, {{ object2.value }}, {{ object3.other_attribute }}` etc...

Can I create a python dictionary from the json string for me to use in the template?

Thank you for your help! 
Cam

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass JSON to your template, pass a dictionary. If you want non-dynamic rendering of data in HTML go with Jinja and flask's built in stuff.

```
from flask import render_template

@api.route('/foo', methods=['GET'])
def foo():
    my_dictionary = {'a':'b', 'foo':'baz'}
    return render_template('foo.html', my_data=my_dictionary)
```

Then in your html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-ca">
 <body>
   {% for key in my_data %}
     <h1>{{key}}</h1>
     <h1>{{my_data.key}}</h1>
   {% endfor %}
 </body>
</html>
```

If you want to make the data available as a javascript object on the client side for live updating you will have to make an ajax call and do some templating on the front-end. If you don't mind page reloads just stick with flask's templating engine.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed want to make the data available as a javascript object.  I used the jquery GET request to  update the values each time the button is clicked to do so. When you say to make an ajax call, do you suggest GET or POST request?

Comment: GET will suffice, you are not creating anything new on the backend.

Comment: Ok, I'm having a hard time with this one. When I use a simple dictionary containing object values, the GET request seems to break down : it renders "undefined".